# POST requests to GitHub Pages

Tags: github, github-pages

I made a GitHub pages repo and created a file called data.json.

Then I wanted to make a POST request to that json file. But when I do so it returns 405 Method Not Allowed. How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

GitHub Pages hosts static sites.  That is, it hosts websites made entirely of static (unchanging) content, such as HTML and JavaScript, that don't have any backend server to receive and process requests other than those for the static assets.

As a result, GitHub Pages doesn't accept POST requests, because generally those are handled by a backend server which performs some operation based on that request.  Pages only accepts GET requests, and only for the static content which already exists.  Because you've sent an HTTP method (POST) that isn't allowed, you've received a 405 Method Not Allowed response.

If you want to create a server that allows you to modify things, or you want to use a PUT (not POST) request to modify static assets (hopefully with authentication), you'll need to host that elsewhere.  GitHub intentionally doesn't host those kinds of things because they don't want to run arbitrary code on behalf of users.